# HTTP 302 found response code - what's the meaning?

Tags: apache, http, network-programming

I am sending an HTTP request using Apache httpcomponents, and receives **302 found**.
I understand that the location response header has the actual url of the resource.
I just didn't understand if I should now explicitly call http post again to this other location url, with the exact headers and body as in the first call, or that I am "already there"?

Comment: This is all documented. Requests for offsite documentation are off topic.

Comment: @EJP I beg you pardon, but I am not a native English speaker, and from several sources I was confused whether I should call the request again with the new URL or not. Anyway, I did, and then I got 403 forbidden. This is the reason I asked the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Wiki:

> The HTTP response status code 302 Found is a common way of performing
>   URL redirection.
>
> An HTTP response with this status code will additionally provide a URL
>   in the location header field. The user agent (e.g. a web browser) is
>   invited by a response with this code to make a second, otherwise
>   identical, request to the new URL specified in the location field. The
>   HTTP/1.0 specification (RFC 1945) initially defined this code, and
>   gives it the description phrase "Moved Temporarily".

So do manual redirection to other (received) URL.